# Page Curl in JS for webview android after JS pagination

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview, page-curl

Ok, so I am stuck with this problem for a week and unable to come up with a solution. I have epub book loaded into the webview android. I used jquery pagination to make it horizontal so now my book scrolls horizontally. But I want to add animation to flip pages. Now each page is a column after pagination. What is the best way to add animation? Using Page curl libraries in android or using javascript/jquery.

Here's what I have done so far..This is the code where after loading the book into the webview as

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/books/", linez, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Now I used on pagefinished to add js for horizontal pagination. How, where and what needs to be added for flipping?

```
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String js = "";
            //js.append("<html>"+"<head>");
            String data = "";
            try{
                InputStream is = assetManager.open("initialize.js");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String jLine="";
                while((jLine=br.readLine())!=null){
                    data = 
                            js+=jLine;
                }
                is.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(" + js + ")()");
        }
    });
```